# Detecting a small curve

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

Suppose you have a contour made of lines, arcs, etc. It can be of any size from 1e-6 to 1e+6. How can I detect tiny useless curves inside it? At the moment we are taking the diagonal of the contour bounding rect * 1e-9 and for very distorted contours (where width is for example many times bigger of the height) it fails.

Does any scentific approach exist to eliminate this tiny useless curves?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. E.g. post an example image, some part of the current code. Also, do you want to detect or eliminate these curves - these two things are releated, but not the same. Finally, as your question has the "3D-graphics" tag, please state if the curve is 2D or 3D which also makes a huge difference.

Comment: Do you mean curves in the enclosed area, or curves that are part of the contour? Do you know a "useless" curve when you see one, or are you looking for a good criterion? Is size all that matters?

Comment: I mean lines with length=1e-6 or arcs with angle=1e-6, they look useless (something you can get rid of) until you face a contour with width=100 and height=1e-6... The contour can be 2D or 3D.

Comment: So remove those curves, and extend the neighboring ones to close the gaps. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

By the phrasing of your question I assume your problem is using floating point for geometry. It is a common mistake. Use integers instead and it will become very clear at what point a curve is really a line. Or when two points are equal. You need to normalize all your data and work with a fixed precision from there.